# timer cannot being aplied to given types

Tags: java, timer

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Babies extends JComponent implements ActionListener { 

  public static void main(String [] args){

      Timer t = new Timer(10,game);
      t.start();   
}
```

I´m new to Java and I´m trying to aply a Timer to my program. The mistake is related to these lines.
Timer required intActionListener instead found intBabies. Timer cannot be aplied to given types.
If someone could help me. Thx a lot.

Comment: Look at the doc. The only constructor available is `Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)` but we don't know what's the type of `game` variable, so you should provide more informations.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the constructor an `ActionListener` object for it to call whenever the delay elapses.  For example, if you did :`Timer t = new Timer(10, new Babies())`, it would compile.  In this case, we don't know what `game` is.